# How to maximize the “k-largest” functions?

Tags: numerical-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I want to solve the following optimization problem:
$$\max_{x} ~sumk(A\vec{x})$$
$$s.t  ~~~ x \geq 0$$
$$~~~~~~~ \sum_i x_i =1 \quad\forall i=1,...,N$$

in which, $A$ and $x$ are matrix and vector respectively.
The function $sumk(\vec{x})$ denotes sum of the $k$-largest entries in a vector $\vec{x}$.

I think, based on [this paper](http://www.ia.pw.edu.pl/~wogrycza/publikacje/artykuly/myipl03.pdf) the problem can be formulated as a min_max LP problem with a non-convex form.

I solved this problem using a general solver (e.g. matlab), but i was wondering if there is a more systematic way to solve it, and how in details?

BTW, i'm generally interested in solving the above for $sumk(f(x))$ in general, but the above simple form can be a good start for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you restrict to the linear case then sum of $k$ largest entries can still be modeled as an LP. See books on convex optimization, for example exercise 5.19 in http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf or https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/linear.html#sum-of-largest-elements.

Comment: Yes, but **maximizing** sum k  becomes non-convex LP!

Comment: Sorry, of course. I wonder if it can be written as a not too complicated MIP.

Comment: I heard this suggestion from others, but i do not know how to do it!

Comment: You add binary variables $z_i$ with the intention that $z_i=1$ indicates that the corresponding $x_i$ is among the $k$ biggest. That will be forced by $\sum z_i=k$, the condition $z_i-z_j=1$ implies $x_i\geq x_j$ and by taking in the objective $x_iz_i$. All these things can be written as MIP with big-M.